# Import render Unity3d for VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, autodesk

I am working on a VR app with Unity3d and I am making the scene rendering with Unity but I cannot achieve good image quality. Is it possible to import a full baked render from Maya, 3ds ( for example an .fbx ) with all the lightning and shading so that I can only work with Unity with the interactions ?
I need to get the highest image quality so I make it as realistic as possible.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I imported objects with textures and models, but no lightning. I would like to import an object with lightning

Answer (score 0):

Shaders will always be different, but in case your lighting conditions don't change, you can fully bake the result as albedo, and use unlit shader to just pass through the result. This will not work as expected if you want to move/rotate the resulting objects, however it might work for environments.

Have in mind that unlike max/maya, unity renders in realtime, in milliseconds per frame, not minutes per frame, so there are certain tradeoffs that are made to ensure speed, the reuslts will never be identical (as they are not identical between offline renderers).

Its probably best to just learn to use Unity shaders to its full, just as you had to learn max/maya.

you can bake lighting in unity3d too, which can give decent results